# How to avoid element to be break apart when screen resizing

Tags: html, css

I am doing a website. I have some element like `<span>` in which I put some text. My problem is when I resize the page, some element are "broke apart" :

The sentence :

```
I am a long and infinite sentence !
```

When page is resized (here, when we reduce at minimal width by clicking on side of the web browser :

```
I
am
a
long
and
infinite
sentence
!
```

Can we avoid this particular string to be resized in CSS/HTML ?

Comment: `white-space: nowrap;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set css property white-space: nowrap;

Comment: Thank you, it is right the proprety I was searching for !

Answer (score 1):

If you want specific words to be kept together, then you can use non-breaking spaces: `&nbsp;`

For example, `infinite&nbsp;sentence` is not broken into two lines.

Comment: Tricky solution, I like it ! :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use the following css:

```
span {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```